# Hyperledger fabric transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting error

Tags: hyperledger

I am using the latest version of the Hyperledger project with docker on Ubuntu 14.04. When I try a peer login and peer network list command

**I get a returned error in the membersrvc console which is:**

> 2016/08/08 08:47:06 transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received
>   bogus greeting from client:
>   "\x16\x03\x01\x00\x9a\x01\x00\x00\x96\x03\x03:r\xc0\xeduf9P\xb4n\x00)\xba"

**Here is the log output:**

> /git/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/build/bin#
>   CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=172.17.0.1:50051 ./peer network list 08:47:04.189
>   [logging] LoggingInit -> DEBU 001 Setting default logging level to
>   DEBUG for command 'network' 2016/08/08 08:47:05 grpc:
>   ClientConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport:
>   connection error: desc = "transport: tls: first record does not look
>   like a TLS handshake"; Reconnecting to "172.17.0.1:50051" 2016/08/08
>   08:47:06 grpc: ClientConn.resetTransport failed to create client
>   transport: connection error: desc = "transport: tls: first record does
>   not look like a TLS handshake"; Reconnecting to "172.17.0.1:50051"
>
> Usage:    peer network list [flags]
>
> Aliases:   list, ls
>
> Flags:   -h, --help[=false]: help for list
>
> Global Flags:
>         --logging-level="": Default logging level and overrides, see core.yaml for full syntax
>         --test.coverprofile="coverage.cov": Done   -v, --version[=false]: Display current version of fabric peer server
>
> Error: Error trying to connect to local peer: grpc: timed out trying
>   to connect

**Output of the validator started:**

```
docker run --rm -it -e CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://172.17.0.1:2375 -e CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG -e CORE_PEER_ID=vp0 -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true hyperledger/fabric-peer peer node start
16:19:20.518 [logging] LoggingInit -> DEBU 001 Setting default logging level to DEBUG for command 'node'
16:19:20.518 [peer] func1 -> INFO 002 Auto detected peer address: 172.17.0.7:7051
16:19:20.518 [peer] func1 -> INFO 003 Auto detected peer address: 172.17.0.7:7051
16:19:20.519 [eventhub_producer] AddEventType -> DEBU 004 registering BLOCK
16:19:20.519 [eventhub_producer] AddEventType -> DEBU 005 registering CHAINCODE
16:19:20.519 [eventhub_producer] AddEventType -> DEBU 006 registering REJECTION
16:19:20.519 [eventhub_producer] AddEventType -> DEBU 007 registering REGISTER
16:19:20.519 [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 008 Security enabled status: false
16:19:20.520 [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 009 Privacy enabled status: false
16:19:20.520 [eventhub_producer] start -> INFO 00a event processor started
16:19:20.520 [db] open -> DEBU 00b Is db path [/var/hyperledger/production/db] empty [true]
16:19:21.017 [chaincode] NewChaincodeSupport -> INFO 00c Chaincode support using peerAddress: 172.17.0.7:7051
16:19:21.017 [chaincode] NewChaincodeSupport -> DEBU 00d Turn off keepalive(value 0)
16:19:21.017 [sysccapi] RegisterSysCC -> INFO 00e system chaincode (noop,github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bddtests/syschaincode/noop) disabled
16:19:21.017 [nodeCmd] serve -> DEBU 00f Running as validating peer - making genesis block if needed
16:19:21.017 [state] loadConfig -> INFO 010 Loading configurations...
16:19:21.018 [state] loadConfig -> INFO 011 Configurations loaded. stateImplName=[buckettree], stateImplConfigs=map[maxGroupingAtEachLevel:%!s(int=5) bucketCacheSize:%!s(int=100) numBuckets:%!s(int=1000003)], deltaHistorySize=[500]
16:19:21.018 [state] NewState -> INFO 012 Initializing state implementation [buckettree]
16:19:21.018 [buckettree] initConfig -> INFO 013 configs passed during initialization = map[string]interface {}{"numBuckets":1000003, "maxGroupingAtEachLevel":5, "bucketCacheSize":100}
16:19:21.018 [buckettree] initConfig -> INFO 014 Initializing bucket tree state implemetation with configurations &{maxGroupingAtEachLevel:5 lowestLevel:9 levelToNumBucketsMap:map[4:321 0:1 5:1601 2:13 1:3 7:40001 6:8001 3:65 8:200001 9:1000003] hashFunc:0xa5f6d0}
16:19:21.018 [buckettree] newBucketCache -> INFO 015 Constructing bucket-cache with max bucket cache size = [100] MBs
16:19:21.018 [buckettree] loadAllBucketNodesFromDB -> INFO 016 Loaded buckets data in cache. Total buckets in DB = [0]. Total cache size:=0
16:19:21.018 [genesis] func1 -> INFO 017 Creating genesis block.
16:19:21.018 [state] GetHash -> DEBU 018 Enter - GetHash()
16:19:21.018 [buckettree] ComputeCryptoHash -> DEBU 019 Enter - ComputeCryptoHash()
16:19:21.018 [buckettree] ComputeCryptoHash -> DEBU 01a Returing existing crypto-hash as recomputation not required
16:19:21.018 [state] GetHash -> DEBU 01b Exit - GetHash()
16:19:21.018 [indexes] addIndexDataForPersistence -> DEBU 01c Indexing block number [0] by hash = [46b9dd2b0ba88d13233b3feb743eeb243fcd52ea62b81b82b50c27646ed5762fd75dc4ddd8c0f200cb05019d67b592f6fc821c49479ab48640292eacb3b7c4be]
16:19:21.018 [state] AddChangesForPersistence -> DEBU 01d state.addChangesForPersistence()...start
16:19:21.018 [state] AddChangesForPersistence -> DEBU 01e Adding state-delta corresponding to block number[0]
16:19:21.018 [state] AddChangesForPersistence -> DEBU 01f Not deleting previous state-delta. Block number [0] is smaller than historyStateDeltaSize [500]
16:19:21.018 [state] AddChangesForPersistence -> DEBU 020 state.addChangesForPersistence()...finished
16:19:21.018 [ledger] resetForNextTxGroup -> DEBU 021 resetting ledger state for next transaction batch
16:19:21.018 [buckettree] ClearWorkingSet -> DEBU 022 Enter - ClearWorkingSet()
16:19:21.019 [nodeCmd] serve -> DEBU 023 Running as validating peer - installing consensus 
16:19:21.019 [peer] initDiscovery -> DEBU 024 Retrieved discovery list from disk: []
16:19:21.020 [consensus/controller] NewConsenter -> INFO 025 Creating default consensus plugin (noops)
16:19:21.020 [consensus/noops] newNoops -> DEBU 026 Creating a NOOPS object
16:19:21.021 [consensus/noops] newNoops -> INFO 027 NOOPS consensus type = *noops.Noops
16:19:21.021 [consensus/noops] newNoops -> INFO 028 NOOPS block size = 500
16:19:21.021 [consensus/noops] newNoops -> INFO 029 NOOPS block wait = 1s
16:19:21.021 [peer] chatWithSomePeers -> DEBU 02a Starting up the first peer of a new network
16:19:21.022 [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 02b Starting peer with ID=name:"vp0" , network ID=dev, address=172.17.0.7:7051, rootnodes=, validator=true
16:19:21.022 [consensus/handler] 1 -> DEBU 02c Starting up message thread for consenter
16:19:21.022 [consensus/statetransfer] verifyAndRecoverBlockchain -> DEBU 02d Validating existing blockchain, highest validated block is 0, valid through 0
16:19:21.022 [consensus/statetransfer] blockThread -> INFO 02e Validated blockchain to the genesis block
16:19:21.022 [rest] StartOpenchainRESTServer -> INFO 02f Initializing the REST service on 0.0.0.0:7050, TLS is disabled.
16:19:21.023 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 030 Starting Peer reconnect service (touch service), with period = 6s
16:19:27.023 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 031 Touch service indicates no dropped connections
16:19:27.023 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 032 Connected to: []
16:19:27.023 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 033 Discovery knows about: []
16:19:33.024 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 034 Touch service indicates no dropped connections
16:19:33.024 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 035 Connected to: []
16:19:33.024 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 036 Discovery knows about: []
```

Thanks

Comment: "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=172.17.0.1:50051"  the 50051 port is for membersrvc service. can you try to run the same 'peer network list' command but with 30303 port specified ? "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=172.17.0.1:30303"

Comment: I get:
2016/08/08 12:34:11 grpc: ClientConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: dial tcp 172.17.0.1:30303: getsockopt: connection refused"; Reconnecting to "172.17.0.1:30303"
2016/08/08 12:34:13 grpc: ClientConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: dial tcp 172.17.0.1:30303: getsockopt: connection refused"; Reconnecting to "172.17.0.1:30303"


Error: Error trying to connect to local peer: grpc: timed out trying to connect

Comment: sorry, missed this line in a log "Auto detected peer address: 172.17.0.7:7051"  can you try the "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=172.17.0.7:7051" instead ?

Comment: No luck! It should send the client preface I believe instead SYN EXT characters I belive?
2016/08/08 13:53:36 grpc: ClientConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake"; Reconnecting to "172.17.0.7:7051"
2016/08/08 13:53:37 grpc: ClientConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake"; Reconnecting to "172.17.0.7:7051"

Comment: CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=172.17.0.1:2375 ./peer node status
15:47:48.978 [logging] LoggingInit -> DEBU 001 Setting default logging level to DEBUG for command 'node'
2016/08/08 15:47:49 grpc: ClientConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: x509: certificate is valid for wilbert, not OBC"; Reconnecting to "172.17.0.1:2375"

Comment: CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=172.17.0.1:2375 ./peer node status
15:47:48.978 [logging] LoggingInit -> DEBU 001 Setting default logging level to DEBUG for command 'node'
2016/08/08 15:47:49 grpc: ClientConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: x509: certificate is valid for wilbert, not OBC"; Reconnecting to "172.17.0.1:2375"

Comment: use command `netstats -ntlp` to verify which port is being used, and used that port for `CORE_PEER_ADDRESS`, also for the ip address, can you please try `172.17.0.2` instead of `1` ?